# show the list of usernames inside a div

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am new to jQuery. In my project, I created one Class `User` in which the code is as shown below:

```
 static ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>();
 //
 //  some function to add values to _users list
 //
 public List<User> GetConnectedUsers()
 {
      return _users.Values.ToList();
 }
```

I want to show this list of values in `div` #showUsernames. How to do this by using jQuery?

I tried the below which is not showing anything

```
    /*display your contacts*/
    $('#showUsernames').append(function(){
        chat.server.getConnectedUsers();
    });
```

where `chat.server`(signalr) calls the server-side code(Chat class)..

I think the solution has nothing to do with signalr.

If the above description is not enough then you can go through my code **[here](https://github.com/venkateshwar/SignalR-Chat-application/blob/master/file.js)**

EDIT:  **User.cs**

```
public class User
{
    public User(string ConnID, string Username)
    {
        Name = Username;
        ConnectionID = ConnID;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calls to the server are async (like all javascript ajax calls). Attach a .done handler to get the results (this is all in the documentation https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs).

Change your code to be like this:

```
chat.server.getConnectedUsers().done(function(users) {
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
        // Write javascript here to append users to the list
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for response.. actually my `User` class has two arguments...so the above code not showing anything. The `users` in the above code are comprised of **username** and **ConnectionId**. How to get both values then. I edited my post with the `User.cs`.    please check..  I tried `users.Name.Length` (not working)

Comment: Still this is not working. As `users` has two properties.. name and connectionId(two arguments of `User` class Constructor). How to show them? please check my edited question.

Comment: I'm lost as to what you're asking. Do you want me to tell you how to update html with javascript?