# Function to add and remove a username

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

In my chat application project, I am trying to broadcast usernames to all the users whenever a new user is connected to a server. and remove a username whenever the user leaves the server. The below is the code which I have tried by going through tutorials. (please check the `file.js` file which is not showing the desired output)

**Chat.cs** (*Working*) --> Implements "Hub" class of SignalR

```
public class Chat : Hub 
{ 
    /* showing only related content */
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>();

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {            
        var user = _users[Context.ConnectionId]; //user as ConnectionId
        User removedUser; //new class object
        _users.TryRemove(Context.ConnectionId, out removedUser);
        return Clients.All.leave(user, DateTime.Now.ToString()); //dynamic expression
    }

    public void Joined()
    {
        User user = new User(Context.ConnectionId, Clients.Caller.username);
        _users.TryAdd(user.ConnectionID, user);
        Clients.All.joins(user.ConnectionID, user.Name, DateTime.Now); //dynamic expression
    }
}
```

**User.cs** (*Working*)

```
public class User
{
    public User(string ConnID, string Username)
    {
        Name = Username;
        ConnectionID = ConnID;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
}
```

**file.js** (*not working*)

```
var chatUsername = window.prompt("Enter Username:", "");  //username
var chat = $.connection.chat;  //connection
//
chat.client.joins = function (ConnectionId, name, Date) {
    ConnectionId = 1; /* given value to just test */
    name = chatUsername;
};

chat.client.leave = function (user, date) {
    user = "";  //making the string empty so that the disconnected user value will be lost.
};

//Here is the connection which calls the "Joined" function of the server (Chat.cs)
```

What should I write in `file.js` functions (***joins*** and ***leave***) so that I will get the desired result as I mentioned above. Before asking here, I have gone through this **[site](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/chatr-just-another-chat-application-using-signalr/)** which is doing the same but including additional javascript files(knockout.js and json) which I dont want to include.(bcos I am new to jquery).

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen I am trying to write the functions **joins** and **leave** in the js file. The functions which I have written are not working. I mean, the usernames are not visible on the page.. If still I am not clear then please have a look at my js file code which is [**here**](https://github.com/venkateshwar/SignalR-Chat-application/blob/master/file.js)

Comment: If you through alert("foo") in your joins/leave function, they should be triggered.  All the code looks correct.

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen yes the `alert` is working.. but I dont know why the code which I have written is not showing the connected users usernames in the div `#showUsername`. I think I should use the `User` class to store the usernames from the variable `chatUsername` of js file(which I dont know how to do)

Comment: Debug your code and see what you're passing to each of your functions.  Use that information to determine what you want to show.

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen I know the flow but dont know what to do.. I am storing the list of connected users in static dictionary `_users`(Chat.cs). I need this List variable to show the connected usernames on all the users pages. Please just tell me how to use the `_users` variable in the js file to show the usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass UserNames to the client you can take your dictionary and in your joined server side method you could change the SignalR line to be:

```
Clients.All.joins(_users.Values); //dynamic expression
```

Then the client version of joins would be:

```
chat.client.joins = function (users) {
    for(var i = users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        alert("User Name: " + users[i].Name + "\nUser Connection ID: " + users[i].ConnectionID);
    }
};
```

Of course you can handle the user information differently than alerting it, but that's the gist of how to handle the data.  Lastly, I'd recommend against passing down the connection ID to everyone because a third party could then easily hijack it.

Comment: I asked the same before in [different manner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13777196/1577396). At that time, I was confused.. Now I realized my mistake. Thanks and sorry :).